# Merging multiple csv files with name sequence

Tags: r, csv, import, filenames

I am trying to merge 700+ csv files in R. I was able to merge them successfully using the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Now my problem is the file names are saved as flux.0, flux.1, flux.2......flux.733. The R binds the files in order of flux.0, flux.1, flux.10, flux.100, flux.101...and so on. Since the sequence of the file is important for me, can you suggest to incorporate this in the above code?
Many Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is the current behavior differing from what you want?

Comment: I want my rows from file flux.0, flux.1, flux.2...flux.733 instead I am getting rows from flux.0, flux.1, flux.10, flux.100. It is regrouping my files and then merging them, which I do not want. Also, I cannot control the naming of the files as these auto-generated file names.

Answer (score 1):

My pipeline for things like that is to get the list of all the files (as you did), turn it into a `tbl`/`data.frame` and than using `map`to read the files and `unnest()` them. That why I can keep the path/file name for each file I loaded.

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(path = "path",
                       full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE,
                       pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
tbl_df() %>%
mutate(data = map(value, read.csv)) %>%
arrange(value) %>%
unnest(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. A silly question here. What does the value store? The file name or the values of different columns inside the csv file.

Comment: Glad I could help and sorry, had to be more clear there. When ever you turn a `vector` to `tbl_df()` the column name will be by default "value". In this case it will be the path. In addition, I see you're new to SO. If you feel the answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  But still, I am getting the same result, just that there is another column with the path name.

Comment: I tried running the could on my own files. The `value` variable will be your paths

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another answer using your own approach. I've just added a function that reads the csv and adds a new column called 'file' with the name of the file without the extension.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(readr) 

df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
    lapply(function(x) {a <- read_csv(x);
                        mutate(a, file = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))}) %>%
    bind_rows
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help. Your code worked but could not solve my problem. I need to extract the data from the merged file in a sequence. In the current case, I will have to extract in sets of 10 which is again very time consuming as I have 700+ files

Comment: May be I didn't understood it well. The thing is that you what to add an attribute that represents the file series that you merged. For instance, having 10 files and wanting to identified the merged files by, for instance blocks/series of 5. In this case you would have a new column with the identifier '1to5' and '6to10' or may be 'flux1' and 'flux2' or may be 'flux5' and 'flux10' ?

Comment: Actually, my file names are stored as flux.0 flux.1, flux.2.....flux.733. Each file is having 7 columns and 1 row. My aim was to combine these files to have 1 file with 733 rows and 7 columns. But the trick was I want data stored in the file to be the same as the file name (i.e. in a sequence representing output for a particular set). I am a beginner to R and thus having so much trouble doing this.