# How can I import multiple .txt files within different folders into the same data object in R?

Tags: r, import

I have multiple .txt files I want to import into the same object in R. However, each of the files are within different folders. When I run the code below, it results in a matrix. How do I get into an object?

```
library(readtext)

processFile <- function(f) {
    df <- readtext(f)
}

text.files <- list.files(path=training_folder, recursive=T, pattern="*.txt", full.names = T)
result     <- sapply(text.files, processFile)
```

Comment: training_folder has the path to the main directory.

Comment: A `matrix` is an object. If you want a `data.frame`, you can use `as.data.frame()` on the matrix. Also, your `processFile` function is pointless---it essentially just renames `readtext`. Don't bother with that, just do `result = as.data.frame(sapply(text.files, readtext))`.

Comment: FYI @Gregor - this is a bit pedantic maybe, but `is.object(matrix())` is `#FALSE`. AFAIK an object is defined in R as having an explicit class attribute set (as opposed to implicit class).  A bit obscure, and almost certainly not what OP understood by the term either

Comment: What about a list? list_with_txt_files = lapply(text.files,readtext).

Comment: try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782183/merging-multiple-csv-files-with-name-sequence/54782310?noredirect=1#comment96348754_54782310

Comment: @dww `?is.object`'s headline is "*Is an object internally classed*", and goes on to say *"this is a very efficient way to check if an object has a class attribute,"* implying that objects can exist with or without class attributes.

Comment: The `is.object` help page links out to `?class`, which says *'Many R objects have a class attribute.... If the object does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, notably "matrix", "array", "function" or "numeric".'* So I `is.object()` is a misnomer, and you should not use it implicitly or explicitly to determine whether something is truly an object - just whether it has a class attribute. Matrices are specifically called out as "notable" objects with an implicit class.

Comment: @dww I'd also refer to the classic John Chambers quote, "*“To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful: -Everything that exists is an object.
-Everything that happens is a function call."* discussed in some detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34376318/903061). If John Chambers can get away with calling *everything that exists* an object, I don't think calling a matrix an object is objectionable.

Comment: Thanks folks! It worked, and I learnt quite a bit from your conversation.